# How Microsoft.Bcl.Async works?

Tags: c#, .net, async-await, base-class-library

`Microsoft.Bcl.Async` enables developers to use `async/await` keywords without .NET Framework 4.5 that they are supposed to target to use them.

That's great, thanks to the incredibly hard work of people in the Microsoft CLR and language teams.

Now I am curious how this can work.

`async/await` require the compiler to do some heavy lifting to turn code into something that can   do await operations.

The compiler *originally* throws compile errors under .NET Framework 4.0, even if it clearly knows what `async/await` mean(Visual Studio 2012/2013.)

So how does this library tell the compiler not to throw specific compile errors related to asynchronous operations, and do some code lifting just like being under .NET Framework 4.5?

Comment: I edited just one more time to change it from causing to cause. But still thanks for editing.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`async/await` is nothing but C# 5.0 compiler transformation. There is no `async/await` at `IL` level.

One simple example would be the `using() { }` statement which is also a compiler transformation. It just converts the `using` statement to `try/finally` block. However, there is a dependency on existence of `IDisposable` interface which is defined in .NET 1.1.

Similarly, the `async/await` transformation depends on certain types like `IAsyncStateMachine` interface which are defined in .NET 4.5. The `Microsoft.Bcl.Async` gets those type definitions  to .NET 4.0.

**EDIT**

> How does the Microsoft.Bcl.Async assembly cause the compiler to recognize a new keyword (async/await)?

No it does not. C# 5.0 compiler already knows about the keywords and what to do with them. However, it can't find the required types as project is targeted to .NET 4.0.  The `Microsoft.Bcl.Async` package brings in those types.

Comment: Thank you. But how does Microsoft.Bcl.Async tell the compiler to use their own type that works like IAsyncStateMachine instead? I think the compiler always looks for the designated type to operate async/await?

Comment: Right, `Microsoft.Bcl.Async` has the same namespaces and same type names as defined in .NET 4.5.

Comment: For more information on the compiler types, see [Jon Skeet's eduasync series](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/tags/Eduasync/default.aspx).

Comment: The link in the previous comment is dead; currently, [Jon Skeet's eduasync series can be found here](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2011/05/08/eduasync-part-1-introduction/).

Answer (score -3):

MS2012 is installing .net 4.5 so you cannot get 'compile errors with 4.0' as you described

Comment: While 4.5 is the new default in VS2012, you can still develop with .NET 4.0, where the compiler **does** raise an error. The only practical difference between VS2010 and VS2012 is in the error description.

Comment: I do get compiler errors with 4.0 but surely the error is not about async/await but missing certain type such as System.Runtime.CompilerServices.IAsyncStateMachine. I appreciate it.