# Why different versions of Visual Studio will output different result of the same code?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

I use the **.NET 4** (*not .NET 4.5* or any other version of the framework!)

Why **different versions of Visual Studio** will output different result of the same code using the **SAME .NET Framework**?

I have the following

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var values = new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
    var funcs = new List<Func<int>>();

    foreach (var v in values) {
        funcs.Add(() => v * 10);
    }

    foreach (var f in funcs) {
        Console.WriteLine(f());
    }

    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

In Visual Studio **2013** the output is `10 20 30 40 50` (Target .NET v == 4).
In Visual Studio **2010** the output is `50 50 50 50 50` (Target .NET v == 4).

Where is the problem? How to identify the **C#** (not the .NET!) version used by each `Studio` for the **`.NET 4`**

> C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319>csc /?
>   Microsoft (R) Visual C# Compiler version 4.0.30319.33440
>   for Microsoft (R) .NET Framework 4.5
>
> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio **10.0**\VC>csc /?
>   Microsoft (R) Visual C# **Compiler version 4**.0.30319.33440
>   for Microsoft (R) .NET Framework 4.5
>
> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio **12.0**>csc /?
>   Microsoft (R) Visual C# **Compiler version 12**.0.30110.0
>   for C# 5

## EDIT

Can I say that

```
VS 2010 == C# 4
VS 2013 == C# 5
```

**and this independently of the target framework of the concrete solution?**

Comment: I display the output of `csc /?` on my machine

Comment: I think it's explained in [Has foreach's use of variables been changed in C# 5?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12112881/has-foreachs-use-of-variables-been-changed-in-c-sharp-5).

Comment: @Habib not a duplicate. my question is **why different Visual Studio  targeting the same .Net outputs different result**

Comment: @serhio, the main reason is because Visual studio 2013 uses C# 5.0 compiler by default. That is why the duplicate linked question.

Comment: @Habib  When I target the .NET 4 framework, it also uses the C# 5 compiler?

Comment: @serhio, See [Untangling the Versions By Jon Skeet](http://csharpindepth.com/articles/chapter1/versions.aspx)

Comment: The answer is no, reference assemblies are used. And VS 2010 doesn't work with .Net 4.5 reference assemblies, so you can't compile .Net 4.5 application using VS 2010.

Comment: Yes, target framework doesn't change the compiler used.

Comment: @serhio Yes, if you targeted .NET 2.0  it would still use the C# 5 compiler. The compiler version and the framework version are totally independent of each other. The compiler version is decided by which version of VS you use but it is fixed and the framework version is settable by project.

Comment: The question is now wrong. 2013 automatically installs framework 4.5.1 and targets that automatically

Comment: @Ofiris, forget about **.NET 4.5, I don't use it** in this example

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From Eric Lippert's [blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/11/12/closing-over-the-loop-variable-considered-harmful.aspx):

> In C# 5, the loop variable of a foreach will be logically inside the
>   loop, and therefore closures will close over a fresh copy of the
>   variable each time.

And a quote from MSDN:

> Visual Studio 2010 will not let you develop using C# 5.  The new C# 5
>   language features are part of the compiler, and will be included in
>   the Visual Studio 2012 compiler.  Even if you install .NET 4.5, this
>   will not let you take advantage of the new features of the language
>   (such as async/await), as these require a new compiler to use.

`VS2013` works with only `C# 5.0` compiler and you can target various .NET frameworks. Because of this, you use get C# 5.0 features like async/await and still target .NET 4.0.

Comment: When I target VS **2013** to the **.NET 4** framework, it also uses the C# 5 compiler?

Comment: @serhio: Yes, right. VS2013 works with only C# 5.0 compiler and you can target various .NET frameworks. Because of this, you use get C# 5.0 features like `async/await` and still target .NET 4.0.

Comment: Added the comment to the answer, very relevant.

Comment: ok, but how about my CSC output? it says that it uses the C# 4??

Comment: Where do you run it from ? for VS2013, use `All programs --> VS2013 --> VS Tools -> Dev Command --> csc`

Comment: @Ofiris as you can see in the post, I run it from `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319>csc /?`

Comment: @YK1 I tried but I can't use the async/await targeting .net 4, because not al types used by async await are present in that framework.

Comment: @serhio: To get the required types for `async/await`, add NuGet package Microsoft.Bcl.Async. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22060691/how-microsoft-bcl-async-works

Comment: VS 2013 uses the C# compiler v12(!) (for C#5), but VS 2013 does not even indicate the c#version used, just the compiler version 4... (see my edit)

Comment: @serhio: .NET 4.5 is just marketing name like Windows Vista is actually Windows vesion 6.0 and Windows 7 is actually version 6.1. Actual version of C# compiler and other system assemblies like clr.dll for .NET 4.5 is `4.0.30319.17929` and greater. The version 13.0 is more related to ToolsVersion of msbuild. From VS2013 onwards  microsoft will ship msbuild with Visual Studio - unlike before where  msbuild shipped with .NET framework releases.

Comment: I don't know if is "more related" or not, but I see the difference between the C# **compiler** version and the **C#** (?!) version, the **.NET** version, and also **VS** version... a mess...

Comment: @serhio: Yes, C# version is marketing name. C# compiler version is internal version - which they can update/hotfix. They cannot hotfix marketing names. I don't see what is your confusion. Anyway, one correction, VS2013 toolsVersion is 12.0 - not 13.0.